# COM ListItem not updating

Tags: development, list, client-object-model, list-item

```
ClientContext cl = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("http://" + "mysharepoint" + "/" + SubWeb);
System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myuser", "mypass", "ntuni");

cl.Credentials = cred;

ListItemCollection result;
List qrtList = cl.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(QRT_LIST_NAME);
result = qrtList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
cl.Load(result);
cl.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem item in result)
{
    if (item.FieldValues["UniqueId"].ToString() == QrtId)
    {

        item.FieldValues["R_x00e9_ponse"] = r.ResponseTxt;
        item.Update();
        qrtList.Update();        
    }
}

cl.ExecuteQuery();
```

My object doesnt update once i visite the sharepoint for some reason. This is wraped around a try catch and nothing gets caught.

Comment: Adding new item works fine.

Comment: Are you sure the if statement condition is evaluating to true? Is it necessary to call qrtList.Update()?

Comment: I can put a breakpoint inside the if and it stops there. Am not sure if the qrtList.Update() is necessary. I can see the item.FieldValue["R_x00e9_ponse"] change once i go through it. Does not end up saved on the Sharepoint tho.

Comment: I just found out that i wasnt updating the Field properly. I was using item.FieldValues["MyField"] and instead i just use item["MyField"]

If you want to post it as an answer Mike, i will give it to you. Thanks :)

Comment: The next thing I would try is updating a different column, with a column name with no unusual characters.

Comment: Oups i meant Chloraphil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference your fields without FieldValues:

```
item["R_x00e9_ponse"] = r.ResponseTxt;
```